# Double slashes on Wordpress Admin URL redirects to wp-login

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I can only access my Dashboard through `www.example.com/wp-login.php`
All links inside dashboard have double slashes before `wp-admin`.. like "`www.example.com//wp-admin/`..."
And when I access this URL, Server redirects me to `wp-login` again...

My `.htaccess` file is the WP default

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any clue about it?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `RewriteBase /`.  Also, in wordpress admin, check the install URL and make sure there is no trailing `/` as that gets used in the paths.

Comment: I removed RewriteBase /  and the install URL is OK, but the problem persists. Every link has //wp-admin, but if i remove one slash... i can access it.

Comment: check the install path in the database

Comment: check the URL's in wp-config.php.

Comment: Database and wp-config.php are OK. The home URL shows without slashes. They appear only in wp-admin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally put 2 slashes in `WP_SITEURL` in `/var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php`

Removing one of the slashes fixed this.